# Warning saving pdf with baltic-1257 letters in R

Tags: r, pdf, save, warnings

In my title of a graph I want to write some letters of Lithuanian language (Baltic-1257), but I get warning:

```
pdf("test.pdf")
plot(1:10, main = "ą")
dev.off()
Warning messages:
1: In title(...) :
  conversion failure on 'ą' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <c4>
2: In title(...) :
  conversion failure on 'ą' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <85>
3: In title(...) :
  conversion failure on 'ą' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <c4>
4: In title(...) :
  conversion failure on 'ą' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <85>
```

After this warning when I look at my saved .pdf, in the title there is dot instead of 'ą'. How can i fix this? Maybe there is some problem with `R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31) -- "Sincere Pumpkin Patch"`, because in `R version 3. 3. 1 (2016-06-21)` everything worked fine?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could try `cairo_pdf`, but this is likely OS dependent so you should add your OS to your question.

Comment: Added information, that I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 OS

Comment: `cairo_pdf` worked. Thank you!